# Opencv install for python on MAc osX Elcaptain

Tags: macos, python-2.7, opencv, osx-elcapitan

I want to install python and then opencv library on my mac which has OsX ElCaptain? Can someone please give me a reliable answer because I have tried a lot of methods out there but it is the same error always. When i import the opencv(cv2,cv3) on pyhton it always says that its not found!

Comment: The easiest path: `brew install opencv3 --with-python`.

Comment: Anaconda is pretty painless. It is a python package manager, includes Python and pip, and has an environment manager, https://www.continuum.io/downloads. If you install it you can then simply open your terminal and run "conda install opencv"